# PHP: foreach msqli_query issue

Tags: php, mysql, foreach, boolean

I'm having an odd issue with a small piece of code right now. I've blown too much time trying to figure it out, so I figured I'd ask here. I have an array of integers ($childIDs) that I want to use to call individually on a stored procedure in a MySQL database. The connection is set up fine and this structure hasn't given me any problems until now.

The *$childIDs* array is set up properly, and the foreach loop *does* loop through each integer in the array as *$currentChild*. I first noticed that only the first item in the array would show up. After some testing, I found that $result was being set to a bool(false) after the first iteration of the loop. That being said, the query works fine with the numbers I'm using in the array.

So my question is why `$result = mysqli_query($database, "CALL get_notes($currentChild);")` is a false bool on everything but the first iteration of the foreach loop?

Here's the code:

```
$childIDs = array();
$childIDs = json_decode($_GET['childids']);
$noteList = array();

foreach ($childIDs as $currentChild)
{
  if ($result = mysqli_query($database, "CALL get_notes($currentChild);"))
  {
    // Gathers all the notes for the child
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
    {
      // does stuff with each row, for now I'll just use an example...
      var_dump($row);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: maybe because $childIDs is a set of objects and not an associative array?

Comment: If that's the issue, why might it work with the first iteration of the foreach loop?

Comment: I solved it. I made a reply with the solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is solved by `mysqli_next_result()`. I needed to free up mysqli before every new iteration that called mysql_query(). Here's the working code:

```
$childIDs = array();
$childIDs = json_decode($_GET['childids']);
$noteList = array();

foreach ($childIDs as $currentChild)
{
  if ($result = mysqli_query($database, "CALL get_notes($currentChild);"))
  {
    // Gathers all the notes for the child
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
    {
      // does stuff with each row, for now I'll just use an example...
      var_dump($row);
    }
  }

  mysqli_next_result($database);
}
```